# How to explain API-centric architecture?

Tags: java, api, worldwind

In my work I have mentioned that World Wind Java has API-centric architecture. I did this because of many articles mentioning it. He opposed with a question "What does it really mean API-centric architecture?. He said that all the libraries in Java are based on API. So my question is:

How to explain API-centric architecture?

Comment: This is more broadly referred to as "service-oriented architecture"

Answer (score 5):

I think "He" has a point.

It seems to me that "API-centric architecture" is simply saying that APIs play an important role in the architecture.  Or, that the architecture defines APIs, and they are important.

Maybe the real problem is that in "your work" you are spouting some fancy new terminological fad that you have heard / read about, but you don't really understand.  I'm not surprised that "he" challenged you on this ...

---

But to answer your question:

> How to explain API-centric architecture?

By first understanding what it really means.  For instance, you might read the following:

- http://www.apievangelist.com/
- [http://www.amazon.com/Business-APIs-1-Kin-Lane/dp/1461113881/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1304210432&sr=1-5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1461113881)
- [http://www.amazon.com/APIs-Strategy-Guide-Daniel-Jacobson/dp/1449308929/ref=pd_sim_sbs_b_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449308929)

(To my mind, that is "not a lot" ... but feel free to make up your own mind on this.  Don't get me wrong: I think that APIs are good and internet services with APIs are good.  It is just that "API-centric architecture" sounds like yet another bit of faddish terminology for an approach that some parts of the SE profession / IT industry have known about and used for > 30 years.)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have found in many articles that Java World Wind SDK has API-centric architecture, I put it there, but actually have never thought what it really means. From what I read now I concluded that SDK built on API-centric architecture allows us to integrate it very easily to different applications. For example, if I want to add World Wind technology into my own application, I just need something like 5 lines of the code and it is. I guess this could be the explanation.